# E-mail рассылка PHP SMTP yandex

Tags: php, email, smtp, яндекс-почта

Есть база из 140к email адресов. Необходимо в течении месяца (или недели) отправить на все эти адреса одно письмо содержащее несколько ссылок на новые проекты одного сайта.

В данный момент есть возможность отправлять письма с помощью PHP через smtp.yandex.ru. Я думаю отправлять в день не больше 3к писем - 125 в час.

Что Вы можете посоветовать по этому поводу. Может у кого есть опыт в E-mail маркетинге и рассылках?

Сервисы приветствуются.

Спасибо.

Comment: VDS стоит копейки, поднимайте свой SMTP и рассылайте сколько угодно.

Comment: http://help.yandex.ru/mail/?id=1113150 уверен будет полезно.

Comment: У меня VPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите на [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/). Хорошо, что у вас нет спешки: вы впишетесь в их темпы роста суточной квоты на отправку.

Технически, вы так же будете слать по письму, но не на SMTP Яндекса, а на API Амазона. С гораздо лучшей доставляемостью.

Comment: Как-то там слишком всё уж сложно.

Comment: Так, слава богу, научились создавать трудности спамерам :)

Comment: Что сложного в [этих примерах отправки писем на PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonSES/send_email)?

Comment: Да, и еще и ман нашел на хабре.

Comment: Всё сделал!

Comment: @exec: крут.

Answer (score 1):

[email рассылки](http://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=email+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Есть куча сервисов, которые умеют рассылать мыло. Смотрите читаете отзывы - юзаете. Плюс практически все они дают тестовые урезанный аккаунт.

На яндексе ваша идея не пройдет, как и на любом другом бесплатном почтовике - он зарубит поток после первых нескольких клонов.

P.S. Естественно все службы рассылок дают отослать письмо только тем, кто действительно хочет его получить)))

Comment: Угу. А теперь смотрим тарифы на том же unisender. 140 тыщ адресов, раз в месяц - 9800 руб. Это год очень приличного VDS, со своим SMTP, рассылай что хочешь, кому хочешь и сколько хочешь :-) Пока в спам-базы не попадёшь :-)

Comment: А в спам-базу попадёшь очень быстро, потому, что исходящий IP один, а получателей в рамках одного Яндекса — масса. Поэтому надо слать через какой-то грид, который во-первых, "белый" и дружит со всеми почтовыми сервисами, а во-вторых шлет через целый пул ip-адресов.